# What values are passed to `#define` when called with increment operator?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, increment

I am trying to comprehend the output of my code over here:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define DOUBLE(x) (x+x)

int main() {
    int i, j;
    i = j = 3;

    printf("%d\n", DOUBLE(++i));  // Output: 10
    printf("%d\n", DOUBLE(j++));  // Output: 7

    return 0;
}
```

This is my interpreatation: `DOUBLE` here is a macro, hence the pre-processor replaces

- `DOUBLE(++i)` to   `(++i + ++i)` and,
- `DOUBLE(j++)` to `(j++ + j++)`

The compiler then pre-increments `i` and post-increments `j` before the addition operation in each statement.

- (5 + 4)
- (3 + 4)

My logic (fails) does not match the output. What is happening behind the scenes when I call `DOUBLE` with argumnets having increment operators.

Comment: You understand the preprocessor correctly, but your understanding of the expressions `++i + ++i` and `j++ + j++` is incorrect (see linked question)

Comment: Yes, `DOUBLE(++i)` expands to `(++i + ++i)` which is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior/949508#949508).  `DOUBLE(j++)` is undefined behavior also.